# How to report "Error Establishing Database Connection" in the Wordpress logs?

Tags: php, wordpress

In our Wordpress site, users occasionally encounter the error page "Error Establishing Database Connection".

As this happens quite seldom there's no general problem with the Wordpress DB configuration.

I'd like to find out under which circumstances the error occurs (e.g. some misconfigured plugin, database connection pool reaching max. connections, ...).

Therefore I enabled Wordpress debugging like so:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

My problem is: the database error isn't reported in any log, not in Wordpress' *debug.log* and not in the *php_error.log* (I can reproduce the error in my staging site but nothing shows up in the log).

**Question:** is there any way to make the error show up in the Wordpress *debug.log?* Ideally with a stack trace?

Comment: If a connection to the DB cannot be established, I don't think WordPress is going to be able to give you any additional information. I think you will need to look at the host-level logs. Maybe too many concurrent connections, or a very long running query.

Comment: The error message is triggered via [`wp_die`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0006dd82d81ad05cf3da6bfe413a495d2128c844/wp-includes/functions.php#L5459) which doesn't log anything. You can, however, add a [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_die_handler/) to [customize the handler](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54611/12496), which will allow you to manually log the error.

Comment: Thank you. I copied the filter code as described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/288101/233775). Unfortunately it's not called, don't know why. As a workaround I added some logging in the `dead_db()` function in *wp-includes/functions.php*.